# Возвращение нескольких значений из функции

Tags: c++

Как можно возвращать и получать **неопределённое** количество аргументов **неопределённого** типа?

```
static /*? void * ?*/ func(/*? void... ?*/) {
/* Первый, второй аргумент? */
return {false, "string"};
}
```

Мне нужно получить из луа аргументы и передать в луа. Некий враппер.

В джаве я бы сделал так: `return new Object[] {true, "test", 123}`

**Upd**
В общем я хочу реализовать что-то подобное:

```
static VarArg funct(VarArg va) {
        if (va.get(1)) {
                return {false, "string"};
        } else {
                return {true, 123, 321, false};
        }
}

VarArg in = {false}

VarArg out = funct(in);

for (int i = 1; i <= out.size(); i++) {
        switch (out.type(i)) {
                case VarArg::TYPE::STRING:
                        log("Arg " << i << " : (string)" << out.get(i)); //my macro
                        //...
                case VarArg::TYPE::BOOLEAN:
                        //...
        }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365860/returning-two-variables-in-a-c-function https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/returning-multiple-values-from-functions-in-c/

Comment: static List<Object> func(){}?

Comment: @JVic откуда у вас в плюсах List и Object появились?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov, честно говоря не работал с плюсами, и думал что там есть некий аналог

Comment: Что значит "неопределенное"? Все неопределенное должно стать определенным в какой-то момент. В какой момент определяется это количество в вашем случае?

Comment: Добавьте примеры вызовов функции, которые хотелось бы сделать работоспособными в рамках данного вопроса.

Comment: Неопределённость в том, что при одном условии функция возвращает одни значения, при другом - другие

Comment: Мне думается использовать std::vector<void *> в качестве возврата функции

Comment: Так бы и писали сразу что вопрос относится к lua ffi. Это же полностью все меняет.

Comment: Уточните, ваш вопрос про С++ или про Lua С API. Т.е. вы не знаете, как в С++ написать функцию которой можно передать несколько значений (про массивы не слышали?),  или вы не знаете, как передать/получить параметры в Lua (совсем не читали доки и как работать с луа-стеком понятия не имеете?).

Comment: Просто вызываемая функция не должна иметь какого-то отношения к луа, а выполнять всю работу с луа должна функция-обёртка, которая и вызывает эту функцию.

Comment: Ок, значит вопрос чисто по С++.